# Updating entries in a database based on time

Tags: firebase, cron, firebase-realtime-database

I have a model called "ticket" that has a start time and end time. I would like to be able to sort/divide tickets by time on the front-end. There will be 3 categories: past (now > end_time), current (start_time < now < end_time), future (now < start_time). Where now represents the real UTC time. I am thinking of having a "state" field in the ticket model which will contain the value "past", "current", or "future". I need a way to update the state of tickets based on time.

Would a cron job running every minute be an appropriate solution for this? It will iterate through all entries and do a check if the state should be updated and then perform the update if necessary. Is this solution scalable? Is there a better solution?

If it is necessary info I am thinking of using Firebase for the database and Google App Engine for the cron job.

Comment: This is going to be really difficult to answer as it's not really a coding question per-se and it's pretty vague because it all depends on what the use case is for your ticket state. i.e. if it the current time is greater than the ticket time, what happens? Update your question with more *coding specific details* so we can help. Also please review [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [Create a verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases it is the wrong approach to save data into a db which gets invalidated by time but can be calculated from the same record's data. There is also a risk of inconsistencies if the dates get updated but the cronjob didn't run yet or when dates are close to now.

I would suggest you to always calculate that info in your db queries by using the date fields. In MySQL this would work similar to this:

```
SELECT 
    (IF (end_time < NOW()) THEN 'past' ELSE IF (start_time < NOW()) THEN 'current' ELSE 'future') AS state
FROM table
```

Alternatively you can just fetch the `start_time` and `end_time` fields and handle the state in your application. If you want to query the entries by status, then you can also use the date columns in the filtering clauses.

This drops the need to have a cron job update the status.